# GRASS has broken my terminal

Tags: grass-gis, osx, shell

I'm using GRASS on OS X. After installing GRASS I can no longer open my terminal to a prompt.

On opening the terminal, the following line runs by itselt

```
'/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh'; exit
```

And GRASS starts but itself. I can't find how to stop terminal from doing this. I just want my shell prompt back.

Comment: you need to check the shell startup files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630360/removing-no-such-file-command-from-osx-terminal-startup

Comment: Which GRASS GIS version did you install and where did you get it from?

Answer (score 1):

A new GRASS GIS 6 stable release is available at

http://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/mac-osx/